# intellij IDEA 14 in ubuntu is very slow

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have an HP Pavilion DV6 laptop with Intel Core-i7 2.00GHz × 8 Processor and 8GB RAM and running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on it, but after updating to Intellij IDEA 14.0.2 every move in IDE get about 10 to 20 second delay.

Anyone having same issue or know how to resolve it?
JRE 1.8_25-b17 amd64
JVM Java HotSpot 64 ServerVM by Oracle

Comment: Same happened to me and i reverted to the older version.

Comment: is your project a maven project?

Comment: My colleague use same version on windows with no problem

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Editing the idea64.vmoptions in the bin folder and setting the max heap to 8 GB (was 512 MB) and the Max PermGen to at least 1GB Change the max permgen size if you are using the default which is around 300mb

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Restart the ide

Comment: Also consider using idea64.exe if you are on 64bit system

Comment: Seroney: OP was asking for Ubuntu.

Comment: @WeirdElfB0yit was for ubuntu

Comment: Oh sorry! I was replying to your comment. I didn't notice you were the one who posted the answer.